# Is there any logging function which allows you to create n number of log files programatically?

Tags: multithreading, logback, slf4j

I'm working on a program which needs to write messages to multiple log files, depending on the number of threads it creates. The amount of threads is arbitrary. Is there a logging facility which allows me to create a separate log file for each thread? I'm currently using sl4j and logback, and it seems to require that the file names be configured in a properties file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logback's [`SiftingAppender`](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender) separates (or sifts) logging according to a given runtime attributes. The general structure goes likes this:

```
<appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <discriminator>
        <key>clientPort</key>
        <defaultValue>unknown</defaultValue>
    </discriminator>
    <sift>
        <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
               <file>server-${clientPort}.log</file> 
               .... 
        </appender>
    </sift>
</appender>
```

By default, SiftingAppender assumes [MDCBasedDiscriminator](https://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/classic/sift/MDCBasedDiscriminator.html) which relies heavily on [**MDC**](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html).

It is probably exactly what your are looking for. See also http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/04/siftingappender-logging-different.html